# Why "experiment" menu item is not visible in "content" section of Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I was read that Google Optimize will be moved into Google Analytics from Google and see also [some fresh articles](http://www.webpronews.com/content-experiments-in-google-analytics-replace-google-website-optimizer-2012-06) showing that is done.

Unfortunately there is some **problem with visibility experimets in Google Analytics** I cannot see such menu position.

Do you have and idea how to switch on this feature, why it is not visible or how to efficiently report this problem if you think that is bug.

Here is what I see in content tab for every site. I am currently using Google Optimizer so maybe it is some collision but it will become soon **obsolete** and want to switch tool.

[image: invisible experiments in Google Analytics]

Comment: This was really bothering me. Users are reporting that their Google Website Optimizer data has been off since the new Experiments release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are number users with not having this option.
Google introduced this option on 4th June only, and will take some time to trickle down to all the users.

Wait for time.

Reference: [No content experiments option inside Google Analytics](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/11aJG3uciR0)

Comment: Experiments appears in Google Analytics finally!